# Trying to import trimmed value from website

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub GetlastPrice()

Dim Html As New 
HTMLDocument, elem$, price$
Dim ws As Worksheet, URL As String
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

URL = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=UBL"
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .send
    Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

elem = Html.querySelector("#responseDiv").innerText

price = Split(Split(elem, "lastPrice"":""")(1), """,")(0)

ws.Range("A2").Value = price1

End Sub
```

The vba run brings

1,020.25"}],"optLink":"/marketinfo/sym_map/symbolMapping.jsp?symbol=UBL&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2

I just wanna 1,020.25

Please help

Comment: Replace `""","` with `Chr(34)`

Comment: Excellent. Now there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add support for the Regular Expresison library:

> **Step 1:** Add VBA reference to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions
>   5.5"
>
> - Select "Developer" tab (I don't have this tab what do I do?)
> - Select "Visual Basic" icon from 'Code' ribbon section
> - In "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" window select "Tools" from the top menu.
> - Select "References"
> - Check the box next to "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5" to include in your workbook.
> - Click "OK"

*(Instructions credited to: [Portland Runner's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22542835/503835), which also provides a comprehensive overview of the regexp pattern syntax)*

Now you can do something like this:

```
elem = Html.querySelector("#responseDiv").innerText()

Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = """lastPrice"":""([0-9,.]+)""\}\]"
Dim re As New RegExp

With re
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Pattern = strPattern
End With

Set allMatches = re.Execute(elem)
Dim result As String: result = ""

If allMatches.Count <> 0 Then
    result = allMatches.Item(0).SubMatches(0)
End If

ws.Range("A2").Value = result
```